ros2 node list does not work
I ran the ros2 node using OpenDDS as shown below.
RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_opendds_cpp ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher publisher_member_function

RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_opendds_cpp ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber subscriber_member_function


The publisher and subsciber are sending messages back and forth fine, but when I request a ros2 node list, nothing comes up, and rqt does the same.

I want to run a ros2 node using OpenDDS as RMW and get the status of the node, is there any way to do that?

Please paste console output as code formatted text, not as a screenshot
